# ¿Por que redondea mis decimales? Problema con arreglo bidimensionales C

Tags: c, matrices, double, coma-flotante, redondeo

Estoy comenzando en el arte de la programación, y trabajo en un ejercicio para mostrar la inversa de una matriz. La matriz inversa, la define como un arreglo **double**, y estoy utilizando el algoritmo por cofactores. El problema es cuando muestro la matriz en pantalla los resultados me salen redondeados, por ejemplo:

Si es 1/6 en vez de mostrar 0.1666 muestra 0.000
Si es 5/2 en vez de mostrar 2.5 muestra 2.000.

Pego el código para que me puedan ayudar. Saludos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **crear_matint();
double **crear_matflot();
void ingresar_matriz( int **mat);
int cof_ij(int a, int b, int **mat);
int determinante( int **mat);
double **inversa(int ** mat);



int main (){

int i,j,a,b;
int **mat;
double **inv;
double k;

    mat=crear_matint();

    ingresar_matriz(mat);

     inv= inversa(mat);


a= cof_ij(1,2,mat);
b= determinante(mat);



printf("\n\n\n\n");

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%i ",mat[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        }



      printf("\n\n\n\n");

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%.5f \t",inv[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        }
k=1/6;
printf(" %i %i  %.1f",a,b,k);

return 0;}




int **crear_matint(int **a){
int i;
int **mat;

mat=(int **)calloc(3,sizeof(int *));

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    mat[i]=(int *)calloc(3,sizeof(int ));}

    return mat;
    }




double **crear_matflot(){
int i;
double **mat;

mat=(double **)calloc(3,sizeof(double *));

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    mat[i]=(double *)calloc(3,sizeof(double ));}

    return mat;
    }


void ingresar_matriz( int **mat){

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("Ingresa el elemento (%i,%i)",(i+1),(j+1));
            scanf("%i",&mat[i][j]);
            }}}




int determinante(int **mat){
    int i,det=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    det+=(cof_ij(0,i,mat))*(mat[0][i]);}
    return det;
    }




int cof_ij(int a, int b, int **mat){

    int c_ij;
    int i,j,k=0;
    int mat2[4];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(i!=a && j!=b){
            mat2[k]=mat[i][j];
            k++;
            }}}
    c_ij= mat2[0]*mat2[3]- mat2[1]*mat2[2];
    c_ij*=pow((-1),(a+b));

    return c_ij;
    }



double **inversa(int ** mat){
    int det,i,j;
    double **inv;

    inv=crear_matflot();

    det=determinante(mat);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){

      inv[j][i] = (cof_ij(i,j,mat))/det;}}

      return inv;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C cuando dividís enteros el resultado obtenido es un entero. Por eso cuando haces 5/2 el resultado te queda redondeado. Esto se soluciona haciendo un cast a `float` sobre algún elemento sea el numerador o denominador.

Por ejemplo: si tenes `5.0/2` o `5/2.0` el resultado sera `2.500000`. Si tus variables son `x` e `y` seria `x/(float) y;` o `(float)x/y;`

Espero que te sirva.